Stop operation if CancellationToken is requested
I had this problem, in my mobile app, if you press logout at the moment of a sync, it crashes.
Sync - is synchronization of the whole state of my application and information output.
Logout - after it we clear all data and services.
It turns out that when we press logout during a sync (2sec), we can still fall into a while loop and access the UpdateFrequencyInSeconds field and there will be a crash.
private async void ThreadSync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (token.IsCancellationRequested is false)
        {
            await Sync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Delay(organizationAppSettingsService.UpdateFrequencyInSeconds * 1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

I've certainly found a solution, but it's not exactly clean and perfect.
This is how it's gonna work.
private async void ThreadSync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (token.IsCancellationRequested is false)
        {
            var updateFrequencyInSeconds = organizationAppSettingsService.UpdateFrequencyInSeconds * 1000;
            await Sync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Delay(updateFrequencyInSeconds).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

It'll work that way too, but it's not pretty.
private async void ThreadSync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (token.IsCancellationRequested is false)
        {
            await Sync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested is false)
                await Task.Delay(organizationAppSettingsService.UpdateFrequencyInSeconds * 1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

Is there some elegant way to not perform field retrieval if the token is canceled?
It doesn't work that way either, first the request is made, then only the token is made.
await Task.Delay(organizationAppSettingsService.UpdateFrequencyInSeconds * 1000, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

I'm trying to find the best solution to fix the bug, I've come up with three options, but they're not exactly clean.
Sync Method
public async Task Sync()
    {
        if (networkManager.IsNetworkAvailable is false || IsSyncInProgress ||
            (DateTime.Now - _lastSyncedTime).TotalSeconds < organizationAppSettingsService.UpdateFrequencyInSeconds)
            return;
        IsSyncInProgress = true;
        _logger.LogInformation($"[BackgroundSync] Updating");
        var waiting = Task.Delay(2000);
        ShowSyncProgress?.Invoke();
        try
        {
            UpdateLocation();

            await ordersRepository.UpdateOrders(_courierLocations, _ordersDtos).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var updateServiceInfo = !_lastServiceInfoUpdated.HasValue ||
                                    (DateTime.Now - _lastServiceInfoUpdated.Value).TotalSeconds >=
                                    IAppSettingsService.DefaultServiceRequestFrequency;
            if (updateServiceInfo)
            {
                await UpdatePaymentTypes().ConfigureAwait(false);
                _lastServiceInfoUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            }

            Synced = true;

            _courierLocations.Clear();
            var orders = Orders?.Where(x => (DateTime.Now - x.DeliveryDate).TotalHours < 24).ToList();
            if (orders is null || orders.Any() is false)
            {
                SyncCompleted?.Invoke();
                return;
            }

            await waiting;
            SyncCompleted?.Invoke();
        }
        catch (SessionExpiredException)
        {
            await RecoverTransportSession().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CatchSyncException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lastSyncedTime = DateTime.Now;

            IsSyncInProgress = false;
            HideSyncProgress?.Invoke();
            _logger.LogInformation("[BackgroundSync] Update completed");
        }


async void is a critical bug, far more important than cancellation. Such methods can't be awaited and are only meant for asynchronous events. The first await will return execution to the caller and the entire method will be orphaned. The name ThreadSync suggests there's a misunderstanding on what tasks and async/await are. They are not threads, and this isn't a thread loop. If Sync itself isn't asynchronous, the code will block until Sync exits

A cancellation token won't abort the thread either. It has to be passed to Sync and that method has to check it or use it in any calls that accept a cancellation token. Pleas post the code of the Sync method. BTW the token must be passed to Task.Delay as well, otherwise the delay won't stop

added a sync method

Unrelated: _logger.LogInformation($"[BackgroundSync] Updating"); - using interpolated strings as log message template is explicitly discouraged by microsoft, although it's not even interpolating anything here..

ShowSyncProgress?.Invoke(); - consider passing IProgress<T> instead.

This looks like you are trying to implement a recurring task execution. For that, you may want to consider a hosted BackGroundService, if you are on Azure maybe a Timer-Triggered Function, or otherwise one of the few Scheduling Frameworks (Quartz.NET, and whatnot ...) , but maybe also a simple Console App executed by Windows Task Scheduler could do it ...

You need to pass the CancellationToken to Sync and then all the asynchronous methods.  ShowSyncProgress?.Invoke(); isn't needed either, progress reporting is available through the IProgress<T> interface. You should check Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Asynchronous APIs. It shows how to handle both concerns correctly.

CancellationToken is cooperative. You need to pass in the token to both Sync and Task.Delay. You should also catch and swallow OperationCanceledException.
private async void ThreadSync(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Sync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Delay(organizationAppSettingsService.UpdateFrequencyInSeconds * 1000, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { //
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // handle/log exception here, do not allow it to fall through in async void
    }
}

Then you need to actually use the token. All those functions which you call need to take the token and pass it on to any functions that will accept it.
public async Task Sync(CancellationToken token)
{

And
    var waiting = Task.Delay(2000, token);

And
        await ordersRepository.UpdateOrders(_courierLocations, _ordersDtos, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

And
            await UpdatePaymentTypes(token).ConfigureAwait(false);

Not sure about this one, do you actually want to abort in a catch?
        await RecoverTransportSession(token).ConfigureAwait(false);


As to what you're actually doing, it's rather strange, and I agree you should probably find a different method to do this. async void is itself a code smell, and there appears to be no other error handling going on. Perhaps a BackgroundService, or some kind of service bus trigger, or maybe you just need WebSocket and SignalR to avoid polling.

I would advise against while (!token.IsCancellationRequested), because it results in inconsistent cancellation behavior. Better do this: while (true) { token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();. This way a cancellation will result in an exception invariably.

Arguably if you know you're going to immediately catch it and swallow then it makes little sense to throw, it's just an unnecessary perf hit. Yes if you're not catching then you should throw instead, which is what the called functions will do.

What if later you add some code in the catch (OperationCanceledException) block? Wouldn't you prefer if this code runs invariably in case of cancellation? Consistency is a good thing in general. It prevents bugs from happening.
